# Python: Method to increment by one returns None

Tags: python-3.x, oop, methods, nonetype

Due to lack of experience I cannot find the error in my code. I have two methods defined and both return None when I call them. Here's my code:

```
class User:
def __init__(self, fname, lname, age):
    self.fname = fname
    self.lname = lname
    self.age = age
    self.login_attempts = 0

def describe_user(self):
    print("The user's name is {} {} and he or she is {} old".format(self.fname, self.lname, self.age))

def greet_user(self):
    print(f"Hello {self.fname}!")

def increment_login_attempts(self):
    self.login_attempts += 1

def reset_login_attempts(self):
    self.login_attempts = 0


user1 = User("Rita", "Jones", 19)
user1.describe_user()
user1.greet_user()
print("")
user2 = User("Ben", "Holmes", 26)
user2.describe_user()
user2.greet_user()
print(user2.increment_login_attempts())
print(user2.increment_login_attempts())
print(user2.increment_login_attempts())
print(user2.reset_login_attempts())
```

The last four print None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any method or function which does not end with an explicit `return` statement (or ends with an explicit plain `return` or `return None`) returns `None` by default. If you want to return the new value, just add:

```
return self.login_attempts
```

as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between what a function **does** and what a function **returns**.
In your case, the increment_login_attempts method does 1 thing. It increments the login_attempts attribute by 1. But it does not return anything.
If you want it to return a value, you have to use the return keyword as such:

```
return self.login_attempts
```

That's the difference between what a function **does** and what it **returns**.